# After mounting the ntfs partition, all files are readonly

Tags: partitioning, mount, permissions, ntfs, fstab

I made the following changes in /etc/fstab, after doing this i cant create any files in any of the partitions and the existing files are readonly. 
Pls help me out.

This is my /etc/fstab

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices  
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc                                       /proc        proc  nodev,noexec,nosuid                0  0  
# / was on /dev/sda10 during installation
UUID=89e6ce75-1460-4c7e-ab26-ada11484cf4e  /            ext4  errors=remount-ro                   0  1  
# swap was on /dev/sda11 during installation
UUID=fb568186-5d39-4a60-9412-c254a0489490  none         swap  sw                                 0  0  
/dev/sda5                                  /media/EDUCATIONAL ntfs  nls=iso8859-1,umask=002  0  0 
/dev/sda6                                  /media/ENTERTAINMENT  ntfs  nls=iso8859-1,umask=002  0  0  
/dev/sda7                                  /media/PROJECTS  ntfs  nls=iso8859-1,umask=002 0  0  
/dev/sda9                                  /media/sda9  swap  noauto,sw                          0  0  
/dev/sda8                                  /media/sda8  ntfs  nls=iso8859-1,noauto,umask=000  0  0
```

Am trying to mount EDUCATIONAL, ENTERTAINMENT and PROJECT partitions.
If i go into PROJECT partition,`cd /media/PROJECT`
and when i do `ls -l`

```
manu@manu-Ideapad-Z570:/media/PROJECTS/Programs$ ls -l
total 20 
drwxrwxr-x 1 root root 4096 Oct 22 15:02 Beagle
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root 2943 Feb 28 21:37 checksum.c
drwxrwxr-x 1 root root    0 Sep  5  2013 GIT
drwxrwxr-x 1 root root 4096 Apr  2  2013 OOPs_programs
drwxrwxr-x 1 root root 4096 Mar  3 10:22 OS
drwxrwxr-x 1 root root    0 Jan 28 18:06 Python
drwxrwxr-x 1 root root    0 Mar  1 00:34 Software_House
drwxrwxr-x 1 root root 4096 Feb 17 10:09 test
drwxrwxr-x 1 root root    0 Feb  5 13:37 Uttara
manu@manu-Ideapad-Z570:/media/PROJECTS/Programs$
```

But when i open the file checksum.c using vim it says readonly file. I tried doing chown and chmod, but also its always readonly.

What should i do i want to access these files make changed and even create new files in there, can anyone please help me out ??

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you must be using `mount.ntfs` instead of `mount.ntfs-3g`.

1. Make sure you have the `ntfs-3g` package installed. `sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g`.
2. In the fstab replace `ntfs` with `ntfs-3g`.
3. Run `sudo mount -a` (or reboot) and you should be good to go.